# How can I use oAuth to secure individual databases within RavenDB?

Tags: oauth, ravendb

I'm looking to use a single RavenDB server to host multiple databases for multiple applications. There won't be many databases (maybe 3 or 4), but I'd like to secure each of them individually

I'm [looking at the Docs](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/authentication), and I'm wondering if this security approach will work on a per/db, and if there's anything special I need to do?

```
store.DatabaseCommands.Put("Raven/ApiKeys/sample",
                           null,
                           RavenJObject.FromObject(new ApiKeyDefinition
                               {
                                   Name = "sample",
                                   Secret = "ThisIsMySecret",
                                   Enabled = true,
                                   Databases = new List<DatabaseAccess>
                                       {
                                           new DatabaseAccess {TenantId = "*"},
                                           new DatabaseAccess {TenantId = Constants.SystemDatabase},
                                       }
                               }), new RavenJObject());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly provide access to just a specific database, yes.
Just have only that db in the Databases collection, and ti will work.

You'll probably want to have separate API Keys for each database, of course.